# How to configure zuul and ribbon for load balance and failover without Eureka

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

Spring boot version : 1.5.7.Release
Spring Cloud version : Dalston.SR4

I'm testing zuul server with ribbon and I don't want to Eureka

I have added the following configuration in zuul server.

```
    #application.properties
    spring.application.name= gateway
    server.port=8089

    eureka.client.enabled=false
    ribbon.eureka.enabled=false

    zuul.ignored-services= "*"
    zuul.routes.sample-service.path=/samples/**
    zuul.routes.sample-service.serviceId=sample-service
    zuul.routes.sample-service.stripPrefix=false
    zuul.routes.sample-service.retryable=true
    zuul.routes.retryable=true
    zuul.retryable=true

    sample-service.ribbon.listOfServers= localhost:8081,localhost:8085
    sample-service.ribbon.eureka.enabled= false
    sample-service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval= 100
    sample-service.ribbon.retryableStatusCodes= 500
    sample-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries= 0
    sample-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer= 1
    sample-service.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations= true
    sample-service.ribbon.ReadTimeout= 10000
    sample-service.ribbon.ConnectTimeout= 10000
    sample-service.ribbon.EnablePrimeConnections= true
    zuul.ribbon-isolation-strategy=thread

    hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 30000
```

## Question

Nomally zuul server is working well, but one of server is shutting down then 
response returned as following message.
What is the debugging point in this case?

```
    {
        "timestamp": 1510040524144,
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "exception": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException",
        "message": "TIMEOUT"
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the dependency of `spring-retry` into your pom for Zuul server>

Comment: @LHCHIN Hi. sure. I have aleady did.
        <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Try to set the value of hystrix timeout larger than ribbon timeout such as 15000.

Comment: @LHCHIN I have modified and test but it returned same message.

Comment: I have added following code in the application.proerties and It's working..
hystrix.command.sample-service.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 60000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added following code in application.properties and it's working.

```
hystrix.command.sample-service.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 60000
```

Thanks.

Comment: So there are two problems: (1) replace `default` with `sample-service` in your configuration. (2) Enlarge the value. Right?